# Python3 JSON encoding error "string argument without an encoding" when porting python 2.7x code to python 3.7x

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-2.7, http, http-post

I am porting python 2.7x code to python 3.7x. This code trying to POST some data to the server using a TCP socket. I am getting an encoding error while creating JSON.dumps(data).

```
 try:
         sei_nal_unit = create_sei_nal_unit(camera_config.SEI_UUID_CAMERA_SETTINGS, 
                        json.dumps(capture_settings) )
         #connection_filehandle.write(sei_nal_unit)
     except Exception as e:
          log.write("socket Thread TCP - exception in sending data [%s]" % (str(e)) ) 

   def encode_multibyte_value(value):
        """ encode values >= 255 as 0xff0xff..0xresidual """

        encoded = bytearray()

        while (value >= 255):
            encoded += bytearray(chr(255))
            value -= 255

        encoded += bytearray(chr(value))

        return encoded

    def escape_bytearray(input):
        """ escape 000 to 0030, 001 to 0031, 002 to 0032 and 003 to 0033 """
        output = bytearray()

        history1 = None
        history2 = None

        for b in input:
            if (history1==0) and (history2==0) and (b <= 3):
                output += chr(3)
                history1 = 3
                history2 = b
            else:
                history1 = history2
                history2 = b

            output += chr(b)    

        return output


       def create_sei_nal_unit(uuid, payload_string):
        """ create a 'user data unregistered' SEI nal unit in a bytearray """
        try:
            assert(bytearray == type(uuid))
            uuid_length = len(uuid)
            assert(16 == uuid_length)
            nal_unit_prefix = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x01')
            nal_unit_type = bytearray(chr(6))                   # 6 = SEI
            encoded_payload_type = encode_multibyte_value(5)    # 5 = 'user data unregistered'
            payload = bytearray(payload_string)
            encoded_payload_size = encode_multibyte_value(uuid_length + len(payload))
            escaped_payload = escape_bytearray(uuid + payload)
            trailing_bits = bytearray(b'\x80')
            sei_nal_unit = ( nal_unit_prefix
                       + nal_unit_type
                       + encoded_payload_type
                       + encoded_payload_size
                       + escaped_payload
                       + trailing_bits )
            return sei_nal_unit
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

and the error is

```
socket Thread TCP - an exception in sending data [string argument without an encoding]
```

The JSON file is

```
capture_settings = [{"framerate": 30, "width": 1280, "height": 720, "bitrate": 17000000, "overlay": false, "gop_size": 30}]
```

I didn't find any clue I'v tried many way but no hope. Thank you advanced.

I have tried in your way but it is not working may be I am doing something wrong. the output of python2 and output of python3 are different and the server is not excepting the data. Please see the python2 code and its output and also python3 code and its output

Python 2 code

```
    import json

capture_settings= [{"framerate": 30, "width": 1280, "height": 720, "bitrate": 17000000, "overlay": False, "gop_size": 30}]

SEI_UUID_CAMERA_SETTINGS = bytearray(b'\x08\x94\xfc\xa2\x58\xce\x45\x02\x8f\x18\xc0\x8c\x68\xe5\x32\x35')
#print(len(SEI_UUID_CAMERA_SETTINGS))
#""" encode values >= 255 as 0xff0xff..0xresidual """
def encode_multibyte_value(value):
    """ encode values >= 255 as 0xff0xff..0xresidual """

    encoded = bytearray()

    while (value >= 255):
        encoded += bytearray(chr(255))
        value -= 255

    encoded += bytearray(chr(value))

    return encoded

def escape_bytearray(input):
    """ escape 000 to 0030, 001 to 0031, 002 to 0032 and 003 to 0033 """
    output = bytearray()

    history1 = None
    history2 = None

    for b in input:
        if (history1==0) and (history2==0) and (b <= 3):
            output += chr(3)
            history1 = 3
            history2 = b
        else:
            history1 = history2
            history2 = b

        output += chr(b)    

    return output


def create_sei_nal_unit(uuid, payload_string):
    """ create a 'user data unregistered' SEI nal unit in a bytearray """

    assert(bytearray == type(uuid))
    print(uuid)

    uuid_length = len(uuid)
    assert(16 == uuid_length)   

    nal_unit_prefix = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x01')
    nal_unit_type = bytearray(chr(6))                   # 6 = SEI

    encoded_payload_type = encode_multibyte_value(5)    # 5 = 'user data unregistered'

    payload = bytearray(payload_string)

    encoded_payload_size = encode_multibyte_value(uuid_length + len(payload))
    print(uuid + payload)
    escaped_payload = escape_bytearray(uuid + payload)


    trailing_bits = bytearray(b'\x80')

    sei_nal_unit = ( nal_unit_prefix
                   + nal_unit_type
                   + encoded_payload_type
                   + encoded_payload_size
                   + escaped_payload
                   + trailing_bits )

    return sei_nal_unit

sei_nal_unit = create_sei_nal_unit(SEI_UUID_CAMERA_SETTINGS, json.dumps(capture_settings))
print(sei_nal_unit)
```

and its output is

> x���X�E���h�25[{"overlay": false, "gop_size": 30, "framerate":
>   30, "height": 720, "width": 1280, "bitrate": 17000000}]�

The python3 code

```
 import json


capture_settings= [{"framerate": 30, "width": 1280, "height": 720, "bitrate": 17000000, "overlay": False, "gop_size": 30}]

SEI_UUID_CAMERA_SETTINGS = b'\x08\x94\xfc\xa2\x58\xce\x45\x02\x8f\x18\xc0\x8c\x68\xe5\x32\x35'
#print(len(SEI_UUID_CAMERA_SETTINGS))
#""" encode values >= 255 as 0xff0xff..0xresidual """
def encode_multibyte_value(value):
    """ encode values >= 255 as 0xff0xff..0xresidual """

    encoded = bytes()

    while (value >= 255):
        encoded += bytes(chr(255).encode('utf-8'))
        value -= 255

    encoded += bytes(chr(value).encode('utf-8'))

    return encoded

def escape_bytearray(input):
    """ escape 000 to 0030, 001 to 0031, 002 to 0032 and 003 to 0033 """
    output = bytes()

    history1 = None
    history2 = None

    for b in input:
        if (history1==0) and (history2==0) and (b <= 3):
            output += b'\x03'
            history1 = 3
            history2 = b
        else:
            history1 = history2
            history2 = b

        output += chr(b).encode('utf-8')    

    return output


def create_sei_nal_unit(uuid, payload_string):
    """ create a 'user data unregistered' SEI nal unit in a bytearray """

    assert(bytes == type(uuid))

    uuid_length = len(uuid)
    assert(16 == uuid_length)   

    nal_unit_prefix = b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
    nal_unit_type = b'\x06'                  # 6 = SEI
    encoded_payload_type = encode_multibyte_value(5)    # 5 = 'user data unregistered'

    payload = bytes(payload_string)

    encoded_payload_size = encode_multibyte_value(uuid_length + len(payload))
    escaped_payload = escape_bytearray(uuid + payload)


    trailing_bits = b'\x80'

    sei_nal_unit = ( nal_unit_prefix
                   + nal_unit_type
                   + encoded_payload_type
                   + encoded_payload_size
                   + escaped_payload
                   + trailing_bits )

    return sei_nal_unit

sei_nal_unit = create_sei_nal_unit(SEI_UUID_CAMERA_SETTINGS, json.dumps(capture_settings).encode('utf-8'))
print(sei_nal_unit)
```

Its output

> b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x06\x05x\x08\xc2\x94\xc3\xbc\xc2\xa2X\xc3\x8eE\x02\xc2\x8f\x18\xc3\x80\xc2\x8ch\xc3\xa525[{"framerate":
>   30, "width": 1280, "height": 720, "bitrate": 17000000, "overlay":
>   false, "gop_size": 30}]\x80'

In python2 the server excepting data but in python3 it is not excepting dat. please let me what is the mistake in python3 code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `json.dumps()` call returns a string.  You must encode that to `bytes` before sending it through your TCP socket. The simplest thing is to use:

```
json.dumps(capture_settings).encode('ascii')
```

By default `json.dumps()` will ensure that all non-ascii characters are fully escaped within the string so you can safely use `.encode('ascii')` to convert the string to `bytes`.

(There is an `ensure_ascii` parameter you can set `False` for situations where you know the server can handle other encodings such as utf-8 but just using ascii is sufficient here.)

Also you can't do `bytearray(chr(6))` as `bytearray()` takes a `bytes` parameter and `chr()` returns a string. `bytearray(b'\06')` would work but all that code would probably be simpler just working directly with `bytes` values instead of `bytearray`.

`bytearray` is a mutable sequence of bytes, unless you need mutability try just using `bytes` directly.

If you rename the parameter as `payload_bytes` (because now you are passing bytes) then this probably works (you can concatenate `bytes` and `bytearray`):

```
        nal_unit_prefix = b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
        nal_unit_type = b'\x06'                  # 6 = SEI
        encoded_payload_type = encode_multibyte_value(5)    # 5 = 'user data unregistered'

        encoded_payload_size = encode_multibyte_value(uuid_length + len(payload))
        escaped_payload = escape_bytearray(uuid + payload_bytes)
        trailing_bits = b'\x80'
        sei_nal_unit = ( nal_unit_prefix
                   + nal_unit_type
                   + encoded_payload_type
                   + encoded_payload_size
                   + escaped_payload
                   + trailing_bits )
```

Comment: Thank you  Mr. @Duncan for your reply.  I've tried in your way what you've suggested but still getting the same error. I didn't understand why. I have also used  `json.dumps(capture_setting).encode('utf-8')` but the same error although in python2 it is working flawlessly without any encoding

Comment: Yes, you had another string hidden away as `chr(6)`. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Duncan for the lesson, I got your point. I will give a try then let you know.

Comment: I am getting some error please help me find the error I have edited my question where I have included python2 and python3 code with output.